# Position fixed in mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, css-position

I have a problem regarding fixed positioning that works on desktop(as expected), but doesn't work in any of the responsive testing tools in which i tested.

The site in question is this one: http://www.claytoncheung.com/

The problem is with menu div, it is set to position:fixed. Please don't ask why it is not set to absolute, i will only say that it can only be set to position:fixed. The reason is the limitations of the CMS that i use, i lost two days on various jQuery solutions to insert the menu dynamicaly, but unfortunately due to limitations in CMS none of these solutions worked.

The problem is that it is a multi language site, and the menu is not an ordinary one, since it is a one page site, so i am left with position fixed.

I tested the site in these tools: 
http://www.responsinator.com/

http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

http://iphonetester.com/ and many more, but in all of them the menu doesn't take fixed position relative to the viewport, but to the parent element.

Please if anyone would take a look at the site to see how it should be and then try some of these tools to see the problem, or even better to check live on iPhone, which unfortunately i can't do.

Comment: If anyone could close this question, the problem was with my media queries, not with position fixed. After two days it just came to mind this moment.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer, and accept it

Comment: You still have to accept your own solution ;)

Comment: Is this fixed in iOS 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone could close this question, the problem was with my media queries, not with position fixed. After two days it just came to mind this moment.